# WordPress Redirect malware white.belonnanotservice

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site is hacked by a malware that redirects to another site, it's called `white.belonnanotservice` any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: can you access the backend? do you have SSL installed?

Comment: I can access the file manager in the server I can't access the wp-admin, so it's just basically the root directory and the files

Comment: I do have SSL certificate on the site

Comment: I got hacked also and it redirected me to: `https://set.belonnanotservice.ga/next.php?v=1&_gl=1`...I restored my site to a previous date and several weeks later, the same thing happened. I didn't have that plugin. But, I deleted a different legal/GDPR plugin just in case. I think mine was WP AutoTerms, but, I deleted it already and forgot the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in the wp-options table, the siteurl and the home has been changed to "belonnanotservice.com"

Changing them back to my website domain fixed the problem "Temporarily" i believe, but this allowed me to access the website so that i can install security plugins to scan my website

Comment: Whilst this is accurate (in my case), I've also discovered that the malware changed the site admin password, and has made changes to the domain stored in permalinks stored in the DB. So I would suggest a more thorough investigation beyond just fixing the `siteurl` and `home url`

Answer (score 3):

My website had the same problem. A plugin called "WP DSGVO Tools (GDPR)" by legalweb created a redirect on the page.

I'd recommend finding a different plugin since it appears that the plugin or whoever provides it got hacked.

I just removed the redirect and it worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue on one of my clients site. Changing the password of the database helped for my case. Also deleted one strange plugin (was visible only through ftp) and one strange user with admin rights. We will have a professional take another look.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have now deactivated the plugin "WP DSGVO Tools (GDPR)" and everything is working perfectly again !!!!

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem on my website - https://mobilecheats.edu.pl

i solved this problem only revert back the database and all files on my hosting.

I lost 3 days my working but website finally working.
next one update all themes and plugins.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30219874)